# Вложенные циклы While JAVA

Tags: java, циклы, while

Друзья, вот такой код

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int k = 0, i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            while (k < 10) {
                System.out.print("S");
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println(1);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Вроде всё гуд, должна получиться матрица 10 на 10 из букв S и цифр 1 на конце

но ответ такой :

```
SSSSSSSSSS1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: если сделать тоже самое на For то всё ок. А на while не работает ((

Comment: У вас переменная k инициализируется 1 раз

Comment: То бишь добавьте `k = 0;` перед `while (k < 10) {`, и будет вам счастье. Или вообще `int k = 0;`, чтобы не не создавать переменную раньше нужного.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Это то что нужно!!!

Answer (score 2):

Так подходит?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            int k = 0;
            while (k < 10) {
                System.out.print("S");
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println(1);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    int i = 10;
    while (i > 0) {
        System.out.println("SSSSSSSSSS1");
        i--;
    }

}
```